# HttpClient+SSL+ Trusted Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

I'm using Commons HttpClient API to connect to one of our Servers.

This server uses SSL and also it uses valid Certificate (issued by Verisign Trust Network).

My Browser never complains as i connect to the server. But my java program throws

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found Exception.

I still have the same issue, even if this valid certificate is imported to my java truststore.

I used the following simple code to connect to the server..

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
  GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("https://www.ourserver.com/"); 
  try { 
    httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
    System.out.println(httpget.getStatusLine());
  } finally {
    httpget.releaseConnection();
  }
```

Note:
I'm very sure that our server is using Trusted certificate as my browser never complained.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of java are you using, and what is the complete subject name of the Verisign root certificate at the top of the chain of certificates that signs yours?

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.4. 
Certificate Hierarchy look like this...

1. Builtin Object Token:Verisign Class 3 Public Primary certification Authority
   2.  VeriSign, Inc
       3. OurServer..

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an older version of java, i.e. 1.4, it is possible that the verisign root CA isn't trusted. In that case you must configure a truststore with the certificate in it. This can be done with de 'javax.net.ssl.trustStore' system property, but isn't advisible to do.

You can implement the 'org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SecureProtocolSocketFactory' to provide a custom SocketFactory with the given truststore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Verisign Root CA to your truststore? It's possible that the error is because the CA that issued your certificate isn't trusted.

I'm not sure that Java's truststore is automatically configured to trust "default" root CAs (Verisign, Thawte, etc.) like most web browsers are.  You might have to manually enable trust for each using keytool, which I assume you know since you mentioned importing into your truststore.

Comment: java does trust a lot of CA certificates. But of older java versions, not al recent CA's are trusted

Comment: I have just imported this certificate alone in to java's truststore.

I don't know how to do this for the Verisign Root CA. I don't have this root certificate with me.

One more question My program works fine if i tested on publicly available Https site.